# Install wireless network adapter on Centos 7

Tags: centos, wifi, firmware

I have an Acer Aspire e5-575g-53vg laptop with Centos 7 and an up-to-date kernel 4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.  Acer says my wireless adapter is an Intel Wireless-AC 7265 (any way to verify this without having to take the laptop apart?) but lspci is not showing this device.  I downloaded the [linux drivers](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) and put them in /lib/firmware as it says on the site, however I don't know what to do next.

I also tried following [these instructions](https://dazdaztech.wordpress.com/2015/10/14/configuring-the-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7265-nic-in-the-intel-nuc5i7ryh-mini-pc-with-centos-7-by-using-nmcli/), but

```
nmcli con
```

returns

```
NAME        UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE     
virbr0      f3e32977-9fa1-4944-9a50-204b429c2855  bridge           virbr0     
enp4s0f1    48084f8a-39f3-4e73-aefd-62f9a94f9519  802-3-ethernet   enp4s0f1   
wlp2s0      92d44793-7823-4a8a-9d87-a268c77fadba  802-11-wireless  --         
virbr0-nic  07741412-1bb1-49a7-a05b-cdcdcca75bae  generic          virbr0-nic
```

which shows the device missing from the new wlp2s0 connection.

Below is the output for `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at 92000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at 94500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at 9452a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 9452b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at 9452c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at 94528000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 9452f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at 9452d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: 93000000-940fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-0000000091ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 94200000-943fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: 94400000-944fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 94524000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 132
    Memory at 94520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 94510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 9452e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 93000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 94000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19

03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device 08a6
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at 94200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at 94405000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at 94410000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci

04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at 94404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 94400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: does `nmcli radio wifi on` change the situation?

Comment: @Serge unfortunately no

Comment: The adapter is enabled, as I have a dual boot with Windows 10 and the wifi works there.

Comment: would you mind to add the output of `lspci -v` to the post?

Comment: Sure, just added it as an edit to the question.

Comment: You misread the `lspci` output. This is your wifi adapter: "03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45336/discussion-between-serge-and-tmakino).

Answer (score 2):

Serge walked me through and resolved this issue.

First off, my wireless adapter is Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31).  Taking three lines from [this guide](https://digitz.org/blog/wifi-issue-on-acer-laptops-running-linux-qualcomm-atheros-device-0042/),

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

followed by a reboot resolved the issue.

It should be noted that following the above steps with the prepackaged 3.10 kernel does not work.  I had to update to 4.7 in order for it to work.